# How to increment numeric value stored in Objective-C string

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I increment numeric String value?

If it is initially "1", I want to increment it in every `applicationDidEnterBackground` click

Comment: Just convert to [yourString intValue] and increment and again convert to string value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case it's weird that you use string for that purpose but you can technically do it like this:

```
int myInt = [myString intValue];// I assume you need it as an integer.
myString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++myInt];
```

Comment: If it's so hard to understand then let me make it clear: Simply to get upvoted and possibly accepted as the asnwer. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: and to become famous. :P Then you should have been given the different answer of that question which i already answered in my comments.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for violating copyright. But I guess you commented after I answered.Cheers

Comment: Ahh its ok, no need to say sorry.

Comment: hey mike, i know thats weird but, but i wanted to know the logic for that, i have just started learning that's why. .  .anyways thanks for the support.

Comment: You're always welcome body. Nobody knows programming languages right in their mom's womb.

Answer (score 1):

Best option: make it a number instead of a string.

Other option:
strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [strValue integerValue] + 1];